# struts2 jqgrid: onEditInlineErrorTopics not being called on error

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-json-plugin, struts2-jquery-grid

On save of the jqgrid, the action catches a `constraint violation exception` and returns "error". However, the `onEditInlineErrorTopics` function is not called on the jsp. The exception needs to be translated to a user message saying *"Duplicate Records"*
The code is as follows:

**JSP grid Code**

```
<sjg:grid id="gridtable" 
dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    loadonce="true"
    pager="true"
    navigator="true"
    scroll="true"  
    navigatorAdd="false"
    navigatorEdit="false"
    navigatorView="false"
    navigatorDelete="true"
    navigatorDeleteOptions="{height:220,reloadAfterSubmit:true,url:'%{deleteurl}'}"
    gridModel="gridModel"
    rowList="10,15,20"
    rowNum="15"
    navigatorRefresh="false"
    navigatorSearch="false"
    editurl="%{editurl}"
    editinline="true"
    navigatorInlineEditButtons="true"
    gridview="true"
    viewrecords="false"
    shrinkToFit="true" 
   onEditInlineErrorTopics="onediterror">
```

Tried these tags as well 
    `errorElementId, errorText` & `onErrorTopics`

**Action header (annotations)**

```
@ParentPackage(value = "basicstruts2")
@Action(value = "/editDetails",
results = {
@Result(name="success",type="json"),
@Result(name="error",type="json"),
@Result(name="none",type="json"),
@Result(name="input",type="json")
})
```

**Action catch block**

```
catch(Exception e){
addActionError("Duplicate Records. Please enter again.");
return "error";
}
```

The `Json` string created is:
           `{"JSON":"error","field1":"1","field2":3,"oper":"edit","field3":5,"field4":"9","field5":null,"field6":null,"field7":"19","field8":156}`

Tried throwing `exception` in the catch block but it shows the stacktrace in a popup.

Tried the success topic `onEditInlineSuccessTopics` as mentioned *[in the showcase here](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)* and it works fine.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=320